# Two ViewHolder same row in recycleview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

As you know, you can create RecyclerView with multiple ViewHolders follow step:

```
getItemViewType()
onCreateViewHolder()
onBindViewHolder()
```

But i can only create two viewholder in other row, example:
I have a list (item 1 - type 1, item 2 - type 1, item 3 - type 2)
So when i use GridLayoutManager with span column is 2, item-1 and item-2 is same row because it same type,

**I have another list (item 1 - type 1, item 2 - type 3, item 3 - type 2)
**

They will be arranged 3 three rows, so i want combine item1 and item 2 same row, not combine layout. Can anyone have an idea?

```
package info.androidhive.recyclerview

import android.annotation.TargetApi
import android.content.Context
import android.content.res.Configuration
import android.os.Build
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView

class MoviesAdapter(private val moviesList: List<Movie>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviesAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
     var pos = true

    fun notifyLayoutChanged(context: Context) {
        val isLanscape = context.resources.configuration.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
        convert(moviesList, isLanscape)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    private fun convert(moviesList: List<Movie>, isLanscape: Boolean) {
        if (isLanscape) {
            moviesList.forEach {
                if (it.type == Movie.Type.PICKUP) {
                    it.type = Movie.Type.BANNER
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class MyViewHolder(view: View) : ViewHolder(view) {
        var title: TextView
        var year: TextView? = null
        var genre: TextView

        init {
            title = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.title) as TextView
            genre = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.genre) as TextView
        }

        override fun bind(movie: Movie) {
            title.text = movie.title
            genre.text = movie.genre
        }

        companion object {

            fun create(context: Context): MyViewHolder {
                return MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context)
                        .inflate(R.layout.movie_list_row, null, false))
            }
        }
    }

    class BannerViewHolder(view: View) : ViewHolder(view) {
        var view1: MovieView
        var view2: MovieView

        init {
            view1 = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.item1) as MovieView
            view2 = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.item2) as MovieView
        }

        override fun bind(movie: Movie) {
            view1.bind(movie)
            view2.bind(movie)
        }

        companion object {

            fun create(context: Context): BannerViewHolder {
                return BannerViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context)
                        .inflate(R.layout.banner, null, false))
            }
        }
    }


    abstract class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        abstract fun bind(movie: Movie)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        if (viewType == Movie.Type.BANNER.ordinal) {
            if (pos) {
                pos = false
                return MyViewHolder.create(parent.context)
            } else {
                pos = true
                return BannerViewHolder.create(parent.context)
            }
        } else {
            return MyViewHolder.create(parent.context)
        }
    }

    override fun onDetachedFromRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView?) {
        super.onDetachedFromRecyclerView(recyclerView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder?, position: Int) {
        if (holder != null) {

            val movie = moviesList[position]
            holder.bind(movie)
        }
    }

    fun getItem(position: Int): Movie {
        return moviesList[position]
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        val movie = moviesList[position]

        return movie.type.ordinal
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return moviesList.size
    }
}
```